# I'm facing this error in Nextjs 13.5 app when I use contextAPI for state management

Tags: react-context, next.js13

This is the error that the browser is showing from nextjs 13.5 when used together with the react-context (contextAPI) for the state management, the error say something about the loaders are not
configured  to process this file, some sites were suggesting to add a piece of code in the webpack.config.js then I figured that I couldn't find it in the nextjs app project.

./context/theme
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   return (
|

> ```
> <ThemeContext.Provider
> ```

|       value={{
|         themeColor,

This is the code where the error is originated

```
"use client"
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext();

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [themeColor, setThemeColor] = useState("");
  return (

    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        themeColor,
        setThemeColor,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Theme;

export const ThemeConsumer = () => {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
};
```